# Handle exception when clicking a link in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an href link displayed in react-table, which calls a Spring backend application. Sample code of the column

```
Header: '',                                                                                           
Cell: row => {                                       
return (                                                        
    <div>
        <a href=/url/apicall/>>                                                                                                                    
        </a>
    </div>
)
}
```

The problem is, if the url a file as bytestream ,my problem is, if there is exception , the application redirects to a common error page.

How can i better handle this ? My thought is, instead of directly providing an href, create a method and call that in href and handle the response in the method.
Any suggestions ?
thanks,

Comment: any update on this

Comment: hi tony,checking now, was sick last day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) in react

> A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines either (or
>   both) of the lifecycle methods static getDerivedStateFromError() or
>   componentDidCatch(). Use static getDerivedStateFromError() to render a
>   fallback UI after an error has been thrown. Use componentDidCatch() to
>   log error information.The componentDidCatch lifecycle method is
>   invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component. The
>   method receives two parameters
>
> The componentDidCatch lifecycle method is invoked after an error has
>   been thrown by a descendant component. The method receives two
>   parameters
>
> 1/ error: – The error object which was thrown
>
> 2/ info: – An object with a componentStack key contains the
>   information about which component threw the error.
>
> The componentDidCatch lifecycle method is invoked after an error has
>   been thrown by a descendant component. The method receives two
>   parameters
>
> componentDidCatch(error, info)

First you need to create ErrorBoundaries component like this

```
class ErrorHandlerBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    errorHandlerService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return Something went wrong.;
    }

    //otherwise just render child props as normally
    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

So we need to add our component in the error boundary component like this

```
//Then we just need to define our component like this
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: true };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      // Simulate a JS error
      throw new Error("oops");
    }
    return <h1> Hello world</h1>;
  }
}
```

Then use like this

```
<ErrorHandlerBoundary>
  <MyComponent />
</ErrorHandlerBoundary>
```

Comment: you mean, if the href link errors out, control will come to the  error component ?

Comment: ok, so, whatever we provide in errorhandlercomponent, that gets printed, but, my problem is, when i call a link (href)- when back returns exception, then how do i pass the controll to this component ? In the example you mentioned, it is based on state variable named error

Comment: can you vote up my answer that would help me a lot.  thank you